# Set text on socket event

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm creating Express.js app. I want to set text in my pug view when I will get data from socket.
My view:

```
extends layout

block content
        table.table
          thead
            tr
              th(colspan='10').text-center #{data.title}
            tr 
              th #{data.label}
              th Table

          tbody
            tr
              th(scope='row') temperature [C]
              td #{Number((data.t1.temperatura).toFixed(2))}
           //MUCH MORE tr [...]

  script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.js")
  script.
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('connected', (data) => {
      // fill table with data ??
    });
```

I know I can do this with somethig like `document.getElementById("td-for-x").innerHTML = data.t1.temperature;` but it is a lot of work for that solution for large table. How to do this much cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your data items, and for each item use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to created your elements as you wish then put them inside your tbody